# sqlplus: error while loading shared libraries: libsqlplus.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-12.04, environment-variables

- `echo $PATH` gives me below result :

> /home/dagda/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin:/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client/bin

- `echo $ORACLE_HOME` fetches :

> /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client

- `echo LD_LIBRARY_PATH` gives (*set through `/etc/bash.bashrc`*)

> /usr/local/lib

doing `vim` for `.bash_profile` shows below things set :

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" #
Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
    export PATH
```

Despite setting the `ld_library_path` in above file I'm still not getting the correct path in `env` despite running `sudo ldconfig` and then rebooting my machine!!

**what help I'm looking for :**

- set env vars correctly
- run sqlplus

I have been a linux user for very short time...so don't exactly know the workaround...if you can guide me, I'll be grateful!!!

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/420395/sqlplus-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libsqlplus-so-cannot-open-shared?noredirect=1#comment542648_420395

Answer (score 1):

Your `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` does not include the path to Oracle libraries. Your bash profile shows:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
```

That line should be changed to:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${ORACLE_HOME}/lib:/usr/local/lib"
```

Or you can add this line to wherever you set your `$ORACLE_HOME` variable (with export). Make sure `$ORACLE_HOME` is set first.

Notice from your `$ORACLE_HOME` value that the Oracle libraries are located at:

```
/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client/lib
```

So that needs to be in your `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. In some cases, like instantclient, you may need to add `$ORACLE_HOME` to `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Also make sure that the library files themselves are readable.

You can use `ldd` to verify that the library path is correct:

```
ldd $ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus
```

Comment: i lost that laptop, so, cant check...nt sure if your answer is right! :\ :D